# 「している」と「し続ける」の違い

Tags: verbs, conjugations, て-form, subsidiary-verbs

活用のないままだと別物だと思われるのですが、例えば「want to keep doing something」と言いたい時、「していたい」とも「し続けたい」とも言うことができそうです。違いはあるでしょうか。それから先日、「英語で話しましょうか」と申し出してくださった相手に、そちらは英語でも構いませんが「こちらは日本語を使っていさせていただきたいです」という言い方をしてみたら、「使い続けさせていただきたい」に直していただきました。確かに書いている時にも多少違和感がありましたが、「ていさせる」という言い方はないということですか？だったらなぜでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

These are not quite the same thing, although I think it can be kind of tricky because `していたい` has no obvious direct parallel in English. It expresses a desire to be in a state, although if you express that desire while in said state the distinction obviously becomes very fuzzy.

> 違いはあるでしょうか。

Well, the very obvious one is that you can `していたい` a state you aren't currently in. [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10126867860) is a question about `常に忙しくしていたいという人`, or `people who constantly want to be busy`. We can reduce this to [忙しくしていたい](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%BF%99%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84), which is just `want to be busy`. You can say this if you aren't currently busy, whereas constructions with `続ける` are not appropriate in that situation. Of course, `忙しくしたい` also just comes out as `want to be busy` in English, but this isn't what you are asking about here - I'll just say that between `したい` and `していたい` the latter has more emphasis on state over time.

The last thing I would add, although I think we are venturing into fairly subjective territory, is that I think there are cases where `続ける` implies more agency than `ている`. [ずっとこうしていたい](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9A%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%81%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%AD) is the Japanese equivalent of English's `I want to be like this forever` which you might expect to hear in a romance movie, but I think `ずっとこうし続けたい` would end up sounding weird here because there's no explicit action that you want to continue.

> 「こちらは日本語を使っていさせていただきたいです」という言い方をしてみたら、「使い続けさせていただきたい」に直していただきました。確かに書いている時にも多少違和感がありましたが、「ていさせる」という言い方はないということですか？

I think you have answered your own question here, in the sense that `ていさせる` sounds pretty weird to me. I would not say this, although perhaps a native speaker can come up with a situation in which it might be appropriate.

> だったらなぜでしょうか。

Unfortunately, as with most things in language, the answer is simply "because people don't say that".